# Sending file through serial port using expect and ymodem on Linux?

Tags: expect, zmodem

The ATF (arm trusted firmware, BL1, BL2) command line loop supports ymodem protocol. Under windows, I am using TeraTerm and can use its menu to manually send files to the device, using ymodem protocol, after inputting the command `ymodem <address>` and seeing the `C` character:

```
NOTICE:  Booting Trusted Firmware
NOTICE:  BL1: v1.4(release):58e7395
NOTICE:  BL1: Built : 17:39:25, Jan  2 2018
# ymodem 0x45103000
NOTICE:  ## Ready for binary (ymodem) download to 0x451030000 at 115200 bps...
C
```

Tera Term also support Macro to automate the process, which works fine. Now I want to use `screen`+`expect`+`sz` under Linux to do the same...But so far I am not successful.

I am currently testing with the following code:

```
 85 spawn screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
 86 set screen $spawn_id
 93 send "ymodem 0x45103000\r"
 94 set timeout 3
 95 expect {
 96         timeout {
 97                 puts "timeout..."
 98                 exit 1
 99         }
100         "115200 bps...\r\nC"
101 }
102 #stty -echo raw
103 spawn sz --ymodem $bl2_burn_path
104 interact -u $screen
105 expect "Bytes"    # can expect see this? 
106 stty echo -raw
107
108 send "\r\r\r"
109 send "exit\r"
```

It seems `sz` repeately sending the file, but there is no feedback from the remote side:

```
expect: does "ymodem 0x45103000\r\n\u001b)0\u001b[?1049h\u001b[4l\u001b[?1h\u001b=\u001b[0m\u001b(B\u001b[1;24r\u001b[H\u001b[J\u001b[H\u001b[Jymodem 0x45103000\r\nNOTICE:  ## Ready for binary (ymodem) download to 0x45103000 at 115200 bps...\r\nC" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "115200 bps...\r\nC"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "115200 bps...\r\nC"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "ymodem 0x45103000\r\n\u001b)0\u001b[?1049h\u001b[4l\u001b[?1h\u001b=\u001b[0m\u001b(B\u001b[1;24r\u001b[H\u001b[J\u001b[H\u001b[Jymodem 0x45103000\r\nNOTICE:  ## Ready for binary (ymodem) download to 0x45103000 at 115200 bps...\r\nC"
spawn sz --ymodem /home/bruin/work/f5/bsp/bl2-burn.bin
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {31117}
spawn id exp7 sent <C>
spawn id exp8 sent <\u0001\u0000\u00ffbl2-burn.bin\u000045352 13335245531 100700 0 1 45352\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001c\u0013\u00a4>

spawn id exp8 sent <\u0001\u0000\u00ffbl2-burn.bin\u000045352 13335245531 100700 0 1 45352\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001c\u0013\u00a4>
```

What's missing from the script above?

I have another question about how to determine the file transfer is complete. Normally (on windows as I observed), once the file tranfer completes, among other things, ATF will print the size of the data transfered, such as `45123 Bytes`. How `expect` watch this msg now? My understanding is that these two spawned processes (`screen` and `sz`) talks directly, bypassing `expect`, no?

Comment: What's `>-------` in your script?

Comment: Sorry, it's table character, as shown in VI.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing a second `spawn` to run `sz`. You have launched `screen` to use the tty device, so now you must ask it to run `sz` for you, connecting any output from that command to the tty, and passing any output from the tty as input back to that command. You do this by sending an `exec` command to the `screen` process, followed by the `sz` command to execute. You also need to add the 2 indicators `!!` to connect stdin and stdout of the command to the tty. And you need to send the usual <kbd>control-a</kbd> `:` prefix and colon to make screen take your input as a command.

So replace the `spawn sz --ymodem $bl2_burn_path` line by something like

```
send "\001:exec !! spawn sz --ymodem $bl2_burn_path\r"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have the device at home, will try it later. Btw, can you elaborate a bit on "You have launched screen to use the tty device, so now you must ask it to run sz for you"? My thinking was that the spawned `sz` process is connected to `screen` process (using `interact -u $screen` command), which will in turn connected to tty device, no?  I was not aware of `exec` and `!!` of `screen`, I was relying on `expect` to connect two processes (sz and screen) together, and assuming that `screen` will connect `sz`'s output to the tty device...

Comment: Actually, you are probably right. I didnt read carefully enough to see your use of `interact` to connect the 2 processes together. I wonder why it didnt work; perhaps screen is seeing control-A and interpreting this as a command. Note you can give patterns to look for to the interact command, something like `interact -u $screen "Bytes" return`